# How to take WordPress plugin options from a json file?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, plugins

I need to load and save plugin options values from a json file.
Actually, my plugin init is:

```
class GSCL_dashboard_widget {

  const wid = 'GSCL_dashboard_widget';

  public static function init() {
    self::update_dashboard_widget_options(
        self::wid,
        array(
            'qty' => 25,
        ),
        true
    );

    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
        self::wid, 
        __( 'GSCL Dashboard Widget', 'nouveau' ),
        array('GSCL_dashboard_widget','widget'),      
        array('GSCL_dashboard_widget','config')       
    );
}
```

...

}

How can I use a JSON file in place of the array ?
There is a way using some Wordpress API or I have to write all the code ?

Thanks

Comment: What's in your json file ??Can you put some sample json file's value ?

Comment: It will contain the same variables of the array in the init, so:
{"qty":25}

Comment: Try to use `file_get_content()`. may be that will help.

Comment: Preloading the values and passing them to the same function?